# How to import m2crypto library into python

Tags: python, m2crypto

I need to work with `m2crypto` library. How can I import it to my `.py` file? I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

usually just doing `import m2crypto` is sufficient

you may need to `easy_install m2crypto` first or maybe even `pip install m2crypto`

If you are on windows you may need the Visual Studio DLL to compile it

Comment: For installing Python packages please read http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: I am a windows user. The code line is: `from M2Crypto import SSL`, when I run the code, I get: `ImportError: No module named M2Crypto`. I alreay installed .msi m2crypto package from: http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Contributed%20Builds as well as `Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1c Light` from: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Not sure what else I can do ?

Comment: You installed a 64bit version of SSL. Are you using a 64bit version of Python and the 64bit version of M2Crypto?